# JavaScript function default parameter value

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, parameters

I'm trying to set a default value for a function parameter, that will query my server for an initial value.

The end goal is i will be able to click on one of the list items I create to retrieve and create a new list.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function getJobs(jobid=0) {
            {#jobid = 0;#}
            console.log("jobid: " + jobid);
            let query = {id: jobid};
            console.log(query);
            $.getJSON("{% url 'website:get-jobs' %}", query, function (data) {
                console.log("getjson");
                $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                    console.log(key + " - " + value);
                    $('#jobs-list').append("<li id='" + key + "'" + "href='#'" + "onclick=getJobs(key)" + ">" + value + "</li>");
                });
            });

        })
</script>
```

If I manually set jobid to 0(commented out in the code above) everything works perfectly. If i try to set it in the function parameter list i get this in my console.log:
jobid: function(e,t){return new w.fn.init(e,t)}

Comment: Where is the code that calls this? The jQuery _ready_ syntax (ie `$(function() { ... })`) passes the jQuery global as the sole function argument, ie `jQuery(function(jQuery) { ... })`. See http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery3

Comment: I highly doubt you actually have code that calls this so I'm really not sure what you're trying to do here. When would `jobid` ever not be `0`?

Comment: The list items are populated with a key from a list of jobs. Initially the key is 0 to get all parent jobs(id=0) after that every time you click a list item it will retrieve a new list of jobs that have that parent id and clear and populate the list again with the new data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When jQuery calls the callback to `$(function(x) { ... })`, the argument is the jQuery object itself, therefore having a default value is never going to be needed

so, you'll want to do this instead

```
$(function() {
    function getJobs(jobid = 0) {
        console.log("jobid: " + jobid);
        let query = {id: jobid};
        console.log(query);
        $.getJSON("{% url 'website:get-jobs' %}", query, function (data) {
            console.log("getjson");
            $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                console.log(key + " - " + value);
                $('#jobs-list').append("<li id='" + key + "'" + "href='#'" + "onclick=getJobs(key)" + ">" + value + "</li>");
            });
        });
    }
    getJobs();
});
```

alternatively, using your original code, you could of course test for the case where typeof jobid is a function, and set it to `0` instead ... i.e.

```
$(function getJobs(jobid) {
    if (typeof jobid === 'function') {
        jobid = 0;
    }
    console.log("jobid: " + jobid);
    let query = {id: jobid};
    console.log(query);
    $.getJSON("{% url 'website:get-jobs' %}", query, function (data) {
        console.log("getjson");
        $.each(data, function (key, value) {
            console.log(key + " - " + value);
            $('#jobs-list').append("<li id='" + key + "'" + "href='#'" + "onclick=getJobs(key)" + ">" + value + "</li>");
        });
    });
});
```